# Write custom file name with AWS::S3 using aws-ruby-sdk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way to upload a file but with a dynamic (custom) filename using the [aws-ruby-sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) gem?  This seems like such an obvious need, yet its nowhere to be found in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html). Grrr

The only method I see in the docs are the following, which doesn't offer much flexibilty.

```
## Uploading Files

## You can upload a file to S3 in a variety of ways. Given a path to a file (as a string) you can do any of the following:

# specify the data as a path to a file
obj.write(Pathname.new(path_to_file))

# also works this way
obj.write(:file => path_to_file)

# Also accepts an open file object
file = File.open(path_to_file, 'rb')
obj.write(file)

## All three examples above produce the same result. The file will be streamed to S3 in chunks. It will not be loaded entirely into memory.
```

I've been using the [aws-s3](http://rubygems.org/gems/aws-s3) gem until now which supported this with the [AWS::S3::S3Object.store](http://rubydoc.info/gems/aws-s3/0.6.3/AWS/S3/S3Object.store), but now that I'm using the SDK gem I can't use this concurrently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, the way you initialize a new object is

```
# new object, does not exist yet
obj = bucket.objects["my-text-object"]
```

then you invoke `.write` on the instance to write the file. In other words, the equivalent of the following `AWS::S3` code

```
S3Object.store('greeting.txt', 'hello world!', 'my-bucket')
```

should be

```
obj = bucket.objects["greeting.txt"]
obj.write("hello world!")
```

where `bucket` is an instance representing a bucket.

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new
bucket = s3.buckets['my-bucket']
```

Comment: I see, so the 'key' or 'my-text-object' is the custom file name.  Thanks